# What does "classmate overstock.com" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> And his team's projections generally proved accurate, even as Netflix's 2002 IPO **classmate Overstock.com** (OSTK) lost Wall Street credibility with a series of antics by its then-CEO Patrick Byrne.

Source: Yahoo [Link 1.](http://finance.yahoo.com/news/ideas-fueled-Netflix-founder-reed-134743231.html) [Link 2.](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/news/ideas-fueled-netflix-founder-reed-134700920.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When two people are classmates, they are often in the same age group or year of schooling. When they graduate in the same year, they are called *the class of 2017*, for example. Here, *classmate* is being used in a similar sense. [Netflix](http://ipo.findthecompany.com/l/1183/Netflix-Inc) and [Overstock](http://ipo.findthecompany.com/l/1757/Overstock-com-Inc) had their IPOs in 2002. They are in the class (group) of 2002 IPOs, and so they are classmates in that sense.

Comment: It’s worth noting that this is a very metaphorical usage of the word _classmate_. I’m not sure how common that practice is; I don’t think I’ve seen it very often.